# CSS rollover menu with animation not appearing correctly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This may seem like a repeat question and im sorry but i cannot fix this and its driving me mad. its probably something so simple too.

I have a hidden menu that appears on rollover of another div although it is behaving very funny. when i rollover the menu appears but it does not appear correctly. i have attached a fiddle and images of how it appears on my machine and how i would like it to appear.

```css
/** Layout */
.ts-layout {
    
}
.ts-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 74px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.ts-menu-activator {
    width: 25px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 75px;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;

    transition: 1s;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.ts-menu-activator:hover {
    transition: 1s;
    transform: translateX(150px);
}

.ts-menu-activator:hover + .ts-menu-area {
    transition: 1s;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.ts-menu-area {
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;

    transform: translate(-150px);
    transition: 1s;
}

.ts-view {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 75px;
}

/** Styling helpers */
.no-select {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.vertical-text {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* also accepts left, right, top, bottom coordinates; not required, but a good idea for styling */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    /* Should be unset in IE9+ I think. */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

```html
<div class="ts-layout" ng-controller="app.views.layout.header as vm">
            <div class="ts-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">Login Information</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">Controls</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ts-menu-activator">
                <span class="vertical-text">TESTING</span>
            </div>

            <div class="ts-menu-area">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                &nbsp;Home
            </div>

            <div class="ts-view">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="angular-animation-container row">
                        <div class="shuffle-animation col-xs-12" ui-view></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Any help or suggestions is appreciated :)

also if anyone could tell me why my text is not displaying vertically that'd be great :)

[image: This is how it appears on my machine]
[image: This is how i would like it to appear]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `<span>` tag to a `<p>` tag see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/cvrhxm7p/12/

```
<div class="ts-menu-activator">
<p class="vertical-text">TESTING</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks adam. anychance you could look at this fiddle and see why its displaying different than yours? i cant see why. sorry im not fantastic with css :p
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/66coy6dj/1/)

Comment: Switch your vertical text from `-90deg` to `90deg` and add `padding-left: 20px;` to vertical text.